# Special probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a box there are $10$ balls numbered $1,2,...,10$. We're taking out balls one by one until we take out the ball numbered $5$. Let $X$ be the number of balls take outs, find the probability distribution of $X$:

1. Take out and return the balls
2. Take out and not returning the balls

I believe the answer for the **1.** is using $X\sim G(\frac{1}{10})$
so $P(x=k) = (1-\frac{1}{10})^{k-1}*(\frac{1}{10})$

For **2.** I'm not sure how to calculate the $P(x=k)$ since every ball that's going out changes my probability space ($\Omega$).

Comment: Is it true that $P(x=k) = \frac{10-k+1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10-k+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, this is the correct solution:

The probability to sample the desired ball on the first toss is:
$$
P(X=1)=\frac{1}{10}
$$
The probability to sample on the second toss can be found using law of total probability:
$$
P(X=2)=P(X=2|X \neq 1)P(X \neq 1)=\frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{9}{10}=\frac{1}{10}
$$
Here, the probability to sample the desired ball out of available 9 is multiplied by the probability to arrive at 9 balls, i.e. to fail the first toss. And so on, so 
$$
P(X=k)=\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{9}\cdot \frac{9}{10} + \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{9} +\ldots =\frac{1}{10}
$$

Comment: Have you seen my comment? $P(x=k) = \frac{10-k+1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10-k+1}$ is the same as your answer right?

Comment: Alex, is this $P(X\leq k)$?

Comment: Pls see edit. I corrected the answer.

Comment: I think this is wrong, seems to me this is $P(E|X=k)$ where $E: \text {picking ball #5}$.

Comment: OK, my apologies, pls see the final solution